# How to define Jersey context root with Dropwizard?

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

I have the following URIs I want to support:

```
/api/ice-cream-service/sizes
/api/ice-cream-service/flavors
```

I do not want:

```
@Path("/api/ice-cream-service/sizes")
@Path("/api/ice-cream-service/flavors")
```

I do want:

```
@Path("/sizes")
@Path("/flavors")
```

How can I define an application level, default base URL for my Dropwizard App?

Answer (score 0):

Dropwizard currently supports an `appRoot` configuration point that can be defined in the application YAML.

Docs at the time of this post: [1.3.0 Configuration Reference](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/docs/manual/configuration.html)

And example application configuration could look like:

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
  rootPath: /api/ice-cream-service
```